# RowSet is not write enabled

Tags: java, oracle

Please help me out, I am trying to update the value of one column in a rowset but I am continously getting an exception..that rowset is not write enabled.
I searched a lot but didn't find a way to make the rowset write enabled.
Mentioning below the code that I am using and the following exception:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", uname, pwd);

        String query = "select * from " + table;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        OracleCachedRowSet oracleCachedRowSet = new OracleCachedRowSet();
        oracleCachedRowSet.populate(rset);
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = oracleCachedRowSet.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();

        while (oracleCachedRowSet.next()) {

            oracleCachedRowSet.updateBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal(99));
            oracleCachedRowSet.updateRow();
            oracleCachedRowSet.acceptChanges();
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {

                System.out.print(oracleCachedRowSet.getString(i) + " ");

            }
        }
    }
```

Exception coming on executing the above code :

```
java.sql.SQLException: The RowSet is not write enabled
    at oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet.checkColumnIndex(OracleCachedRowSet.java:912)
    at oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet.updateObject(OracleCachedRowSet.java:5931)
    at oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet.updateBigDecimal(OracleCachedRowSet.java:6430)
    at Test.getDBConnection(Test.java:86)
    at Test.main(Test.java:37)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting:

```
oracleCachedRowSet.setReadOnly(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...its working now after setting read only false.

Answer (score -1):

Javadoc for [`ResultSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) tells us

> A default ResultSet object is not updatable and has a cursor that moves forward only.

I *guess*, the message of your exception is related to that issue. The javaDoc provides an example how to create a scrollable and updateable result set:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                                  ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM TABLE2");
// rs will be scrollable, will not show changes made by others,
// and will be updatable
```

Comment: The question involves RowSet, not ResultSet.

Comment: A RowSet **is-a** ResultSet. But, however, the other answer had the solution to *this* problem.